IOUSBHostInterface::Open for interrupt interfaces works on iPad Air but not iPad Pro
I am trying to open the Communication Control class IOUSBHostInterface in my USB driver, but it only seems to open on iPad Airs and not iPad Pros. I'm calling
ivars->interruptInterface->Open(this, 0, NULL);
After retrieving the interruptInterface from the device's InterfaceIterator. I try and open this, but on iPad Pros it returns kIOReturnNotOpen (0xe00002cd). I've tried closing and reopening the IOUSBHostDevice, closing and reopening the interface, AbortDeviceRequests before opening, etc. but it just seems to work on iPad Air and not iPad Pro.
I've tried on both iPadOS 17.6.1 and 18.2
Has anyone else seen this? Is there a way to get around it or something else that needs to be done during setup for iPad Pro specifically? I'm already calling IOUSBHostDevice::Open and IOUSBHostDevice::SetConfiguration, and the bulk endpoint interface opens just fine on both models
